# Overlap div over nav

Tags: css, html, positioning

I want the logo div to be on top of the nav container. How would I achieve this? I have been playing around with positioning and nothing seems to be working. They are both inside the header container.

Here is my CSS code:

and js link:

http://jsfiddle.net/4vA93/3/

```
header {
position: relative;
height:100px;
background-color: yellow;

}

.logo {
position: absolute;
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:20px;
width:80px;
height:80px;
background-color: red;
}


nav {
position: absolute;
width:100%;
bottom: 0;
background-color: bisque;   
}
```

and HTML

```
    <header>
    <div id="logo">Logo</div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">| Hours |</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Facilities |</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Restaurant Charlotte |</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Penthouse Suite |</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Gift Shop |</a></li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: where's your html? can you set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: please update the question with `HTML` also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/4vA93/4/

```
#logo {
    z-index:10;
}
```

Or like this? http://jsfiddle.net/4vA93/5/

Comment: Yes! Do you also know how to center the text of the nav?

Comment: Great! How strange I tried text-align center I must of been doing it wrong.

Comment: Glad it worked :), don't forget to mark the question as answered just incase somebody else runs into a similar issue, cheers!